# How to partial download google drive files using java REST Client API?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-client

Using the sample code (Drive Java REST API V3) below, I am trying to download a portion of a file from google drive.

```
Drive.Revisions.Get get = service.revisions().get(fileId, revisionId)
            .setFields(FilterConstants.OBJECT_REVISION);

MediaHttpDownloader downloader = get.getMediaHttpDownloader();
downloader.setContentRange(fromByte, toByte);

inputStream = get.executeMediaAsInputStream();
```

But this is not working for me. Can someone help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How this is possible with Java REST Client API, can some explain it?

Answer (score 0):

@Venkat, based on [**Partial download**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#partial_download),

> Partial download involves downloading only a specified portion of a file. You can specify the portion of the file you want to dowload by using a byte range with the Range header. For example:

`Range: bytes=500-999`

Sample:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
Range: bytes=500-999
```

Comment: can you please explain more clearly in java api direction

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. The trick was to set Range header correctly

```
private byte[] getBytes(Drive drive, String downloadUrl, long position, int byteCount) {
    byte[] receivedByteArray = null;
    if (downloadUrl != null && downloadUrl.length() > 0) {
        try {
            com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest httpRequestGet = drive.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(downloadUrl));
            httpRequestGet.getHeaders().setRange("bytes=" + position + "-" + (position + byteCount - 1));
            com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response = httpRequestGet.execute();
            InputStream is = response.getContent();
            receivedByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            response.disconnect();
            System.out.println("google-http-client-1.18.0-rc response: [" + position + ", " + (position + receivedByteArray.length - 1) + "]");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return receivedByteArray;
}
```

Comment: The question is about downloading a file, while this just returns metadata about the file.